# Stuck with JSON API Call in Javascript

Tags: javascript, coingecko

I am trying to build a Calculator where you can Pick different Cryptocurrencies and build a Portfolio for Testing and Tracking. I choose Coingecko API v3 for this and use Fetch to do the API Calls. https://www.coingecko.com/en/api

The API Calls are working and I get JSON Data from the Server. I built a Function that is delivering the Top 100 Coins, putting them into a Datalist-Tag for Choosing from an Input:

```js
function fetch_coinlist(url) {
  fetch(url)
    .then(function(response) {
      if (response.status !== 200) {
        alert("Can Not get Price Api! Status: " + response.status);
        return;
      }

      response.json().then(function(data) {
        document.getElementById("coinlist").innerHTML = "";

        for (i = 0; i <= 99; i++) {
          const toplist = document.createElement("option");

          toplist.id = data[i].symbol;

          toplist.innerHTML =
            data[i].symbol.toUpperCase() + " - " + data[i].name;

          document.getElementById("coinlisting").appendChild(toplist);

          //console.log(data[i].id);
          //console.log(data[i].name);
          //console.log(data[i].symbol);
          //console.log(data[i].image);
          //console.log(data[i].current_price);
        }
      });
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      alert("Can Not get Price Api! Status: " + err);
    });
}
```

```html
<input list="coinlisting" id="coinlist" name="coinlist" class="curser-choose" />
<datalist id="coinlisting" placeholder="Choose Coin"></datalist>
```

This is working, I am using a For loop to go through the response. I try to Display the Price for a Coin if the User picked one Option from this Datalist and for further functionality I think it would be best that I could call an object like `data.coinname.current_price` so I can build a Function where i could pass a string to it and get the price for that coin.

However, right now I would have to use data[0].current_price for the `current Price` of the first item in the list. The items on the called List can Change over time, so I can not make a static assignment, I think I could do this each time I call the API but it would not benefit my target to have a function that I can feed with a name as a string to do the Price Call.

It is possible to get the Price in the same call as the list but I can not figure out how I would be able to do what I have in mind with that. On the site for the API are different calls listed, one of the first is the /coins/list call and it says "Use this to obtain all the coins’ id in order to make API calls" and gives a JSON object for each available coin like:

```
{
  "id": "1inch",
  "symbol": "1inch",
  "name": "1inch"
}
```

Do I need to do this call first in order to achieve what I have in mind? But I'm unsure how that would help me get the solution I am looking for... I am struggling to find a solution for this and feel stuck, I feel like I don't understand it properly and it should be not as hard as I think it is right now :D If you have an idea of how to accomplish this please let me know!

Comment: What is to do with CSS in this? Plz don't add unnecessary tags.

Comment: To make people answer your question. Try to simplify like that:
I have this problem. I have tried this. And the error is that. Adding things like: "I choose Coingecko API v3 for this and use Fetch to do the Api Calls. https://www.coingecko.com/en/api" it will make a bloated non-answered question

Comment: Your code does not run. you need `url="https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/list";`

Comment: Hi, sorry this is my first Post i used CSS for this Project so i added it to it, the API Url was passed to the Function so i could use it with a Button for debugging. Thanks for the Tips!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this. I kept the html simple.

- fetch_coinlist: fetches a coin list. After fetching the coins list it converts the result to an object instead of a list. Each coin can be accessed using `coins["<coin id>"]`.
- show_coinlist does the visualisation
- addEventListener catches when you select an item.

```js
const gecko = "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/";
var coins = {};

// selector actions
const selector = document.querySelector('#coinlisting');
const info = document.querySelector('#info');
selector.addEventListener('change', event => {
  info.innerHTML = "Selected item: " + selector.value + " : " + coins[selector.value].name;
});

function fetch_coinlist() {
  fetch(gecko + "coins/list")
    .then(function(response) {
      if (response.status !== 200) {
        alert("Can Not get List Api! Status: " + response.status);
        return;
      }

      response.json().then(function(data) {
        coins = {};
        for (let i = 0, l = data.length; i < l; i++) {
          let {id, ...info} = data[i];
          coins[id] = info;
        }
        show_coinlist();
      });
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      alert("Can Not get Price Api! Status: " + err);
    });
}
function show_coinlist(){
  for (let id in coins) {
    let item = coins[id];
    const toplist = document.createElement("option");
  
    toplist.value = id;
    toplist.innerHTML = item.symbol.toUpperCase() + " - " + item.name;
    document.getElementById("coinlisting").appendChild(toplist);
  }
}

fetch_coinlist();
```

```html
    <select id="coinlisting" placeholder="Choose Coin"></select>
    <div id="info"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you Kevin Verstrate! This works very nice! Sorry for nub Questions, i have now another issue where i try to find a solution to have multiple dynamic selectors for dynamic added Div ID but i only get "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null"